# Request count is not matching when load testing is being performed using jmeter

Tags: java, performance, jmeter, load-testing

I am using JMeter to send HttpRequests (POST) to two different URLs (Login and Verification) as shown in the image.[Testplan JMeter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9dDm.png)

When I am trying to simulate more than 25 user requests I am seeing JMeter is able to send up to 20 requests to both the URLs. But when I am increasing the load say for example, to 25 or more, I am seeing all the requests are being sent to the Login Url only but only few requests are being sent to the second URL.

I verified whether my application server is getting all the requests or not for both the URLs but it is not receiving all the requests for the second URL.

It is confusing to me why JMeter is unable to send HttpRequests to both the URLs when i am increasing the load but is able to send requests when the load is below 20 user requests.

Any clue on what might be happening here will be helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you share more details? i.e Ramp up time , loop count? Also how you verified that it is login successfully?

Comment: Rampup time given as 1 sec RAM size of PC where Jmeter is running is 4GB with 4 cores, and I am using Ifcontroller logic so that the second request for verification will get executed only after the first request is successful. After completion of the test, in Aggregate Report page of Jmeter #sample tab is showing different count for Login and verification requests. On application server side i wrote a debugging statement to check how many requests are coming in only in the case of verification URL but not for Login URL. Can i rely up on #samples values in aggregate report for further analysis?

Comment: Ok and what is your test duration?

Comment: The test plan is taking around 1 min to complete when the no of requests are 30. But i did not keenly observe for different load. i also ran the tests with the think time as around 15000 msec by adding a timer.

Comment: I asked what is test duration? for how many minutes you are running your test?

Comment: I am not using the scheduler option (scheduler option is unchecked). I have not set any value for Duration in the scheduler section of ThreadGroup.

Comment: what are values you pass in post request of login? I doubt that it is not logging successfully.

Comment: ok i will check and come back with the result tomorrow.

Comment: I inserted debug statements in the code and verified the tomcat log. All login attempts were successful and i also verified whether tomcat is sending the query requests from verification page to the postgresql server or not. At DB server end i am receiving all the queries and DB server is responding to all queries. However, tomcat is not receiving responses to all sql queries, thatswhy, i am getting different count for login and verification pages. But i am unable to figure out why tomcat is not receiving responses to all queries. I increased connectionTimeout value to 120000 msec still no use